# Extract text of one column based on similar text from another column in r

Tags: r, string, extract, text-extraction

I'm writing this post because I'm currently working on a R project and I'm facing some issues.

Basically, I'm trying to extract some text in one column based on the text present in another column. These two expressions are not totally similar. I'll give you an example of what I have and what I would like :

```
#I have this table and I would like to extract what is in column 2 based on what I have in column 1
df <- data.frame(col_1 = c("Pamela Da Costa", "Gaelle Bourget", "Etienne Klein"),
                 col_2 = c("Pamela Giannotti", "Francois Sommet", "Pamela Da Costa)) Gionvani"))

# I would like this table : 
df2 <- data.frame(col_1 = c("Pamela Da Costa", "Gaelle Bourget", "Etienne Klein"),
                  col_2 = c("Pamela Giannotti", "Francois Sommet", "Pamela Da Costa Giovanni"),
                  extracted = c(NA, NA, "Pamela Da Costa") )
```

I tried to do write a function in order to do so, using stringr

```
extract_name <- function(name1, name2) {
  name_extract <- str_extract(name1, name2)
  ifelse(is.na(name_extract), NA, name_extract)
}

df$col_extract <- extract_name(df$col_1, df$col_2)
```

But sadly it doesn't work :

```
df2 <- data.frame(col_1 = c("Pamela Da Costa", "Gaelle Bourget", "Etienne Klein"),
                  col_2 = c("Pamela Giannotti", "Francois Sommet", "Pamela Da Costa Giovanni),
                  extracted = c(NA, NA, NA) )
```

I also tried something with stringdist but it also doesn't work and it takes a lot of time to compute.

Best regards and thanks in advance for who might help me !

Comment: There's some formatting issues with your code, can you fix it? from what I understand, stringdist should be the way to go, but calculating string distances is a costly operation. I'm not sure how each function is implemented, but some of those should be more efficient than others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `|` to match multiple patterns:

```r
df$col_3 <- str_extract(df$col_2, paste(df$col_1, collapse = "|"))

#            col_1                    col_2           col_3
#1 Pamela Da Costa         Pamela Giannotti            <NA>
#2  Gaelle Bourget          Francois Sommet            <NA>
#3   Etienne Klein Pamela Da Costa Gionvani Pamela Da Costa
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R approach:

```
my_func <- function(df, col1, col2) {
  matches <- regmatches(df[[col2]], gregexpr(paste(df[[col1]], collapse = "|"), df[[col2]]))
  matches[sapply(matches, length) == 0] <- NA
  df$extracted <- matches
  return(df)
}

my_func(df, "col_1", "col_2")
```

```
col_1                      col_2       extracted
1 Pamela Da Costa           Pamela Giannotti              NA
2  Gaelle Bourget            Francois Sommet              NA
3   Etienne Klein Pamela Da Costa)) Gionvani Pamela Da Costa
```